# How can Lubuntu 20.04 LTS be installed in a USB which can boot into both- UEFI & Legacy BIOS systems?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, uefi, bios, lubuntu

Self-explanatory question. But please keep in mind in totally new to Linux.

- I really request you to answer this as though you were hypothetically going to explain to a 12 year old. Im actually 38, but the point is i find it difficult to follow things that intermediate Linux uses are cool with.
- If there is a similar question previously answered(I tried finding one for ~25 mins, found nothing for Lubuntu with good steps -- im stupid, i need steps) , please do not immediately shut my question... Maybe give me some time so i can test to see if it works and if it does, i'll shut the question myself!
- I need this because I have to move around and travel a lot, and need a reliable way to port a full OS without the risk of damaging a laptop, and further once im there, i generally have access to a machine, and for the rest my phone suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much fretting, I asked this @ AskUbuntu.

Thank God I did, because no one here responded.

Anyway, the answer is here. I did it.

Answered @ AskUbuntu by Daniel Massey. Answer is [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1253617/1098871).

I post this answer for anyone who needs help in the future. A more detailed guide including Daniel's guide and some additions by me for adding drivers for Macs and Nvidia GPUs as well as useful generalisation to apply to *any distribution* of Linux :

https://docs.google.com/document/d/14PWThtbylgmqsnQbR8hUbgU6hfh55GJ9N1EOEEbrnzg/edit?usp=sharing

The document mentioned above is written with 3  purposes:

1. Allow you to make your portable, full-fledged Linux install that will, ideally, work on any non-ARM PC that you wish to boot from.
2. Achieve the 1st objective , ideally, on any distro.
3. Allow a complete noob to follow instructions and links to achieve the 1st and 2nd objective.